# Error 91 in class function

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Using Access 2010, I'm gathering information and dropping it on an Excel spreadsheet. When I run the code below, I'm getting

> Run-time error '91':
> Object variable or With block not set

in my class on this line `Set Cci = ChartColorItems(ColorID)` in `Public Function GetRGB(ByRef ColorID As String) As Integer`

The 'ChartColors' class:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private pChartColorItems As Collection

Public Property Get ChartColorItems() As Collection
  Set ChartColorItems = pChartColorItems
End Property
Public Property Set ChartColorItems(ByRef lChartColorItem As Collection)
  Set pChartColorItems = lChartColorItem
End Property

Public Function GetRGB(ByRef ColorID As String) As Integer
  Dim Cci As ChartColorItem
  Dim x As Integer

'---------------------------------------------------
'Error happens here:      
  Set Cci = ChartColorItems(ColorID)
'---------------------------------------------------
  x = RGB(Cci.Red, Cci.Green, Cci.Blue)
  GetRGB = x
  Set Cci = Nothing

End Function

Private Sub Class_Initialize()

  Dim Cci As ChartColorItem
  Dim Colors As Collection

  Set Colors = New Collection

  Set Cci = New ChartColorItem
  Cci.Red = 149
  Cci.Green = 55
  Cci.Blue = 53
  Cci.ColorID = "Pie1"
  Colors.Add Cci, Key:=Cci.ColorID
  Set Cci = Nothing

  Set Cci = New ChartColorItem
  Cci.Red = 148
  Cci.Green = 138
  Cci.Blue = 84
  Cci.ColorID = "Pie2"
  Colors.Add Cci, Key:=Cci.ColorID
  Set Cci = Nothing

End Sub
```

and the ChartColorItem class:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private pColorID As String
Private pRed As Integer
Private pGreen As Integer
Private pBlue As Integer

Public Property Get ColorID() As String
  ColorID = pColorID
End Property
Public Property Let ColorID(ByRef x As String)
  pColorID = x
End Property

Public Property Get Red() As Integer
  Red = pRed
End Property
Public Property Let Red(ByRef x As Integer)
  pRed = x
End Property

Public Property Get Green() As Integer
  Green = pGreen
End Property
Public Property Let Green(ByRef x As Integer)
  pGreen = x
End Property

Public Property Get Blue() As Integer
  Blue = pBlue
End Property
Public Property Let Blue(ByRef x As Integer)
  pBlue = x
End Property
```

When I debug, the code steps through the `ChartColorItems()` getter just fine, the error happens after the `End Function`, and drops me on the line noted above.

This is very similar to some code I wrote earlier this week, the main difference is that I'm populating my ChartColors by using the `Class_Initialize` sub, since I'm trying to store off a fixed set of colors, whereas my earlier code was gathering data and inserting it into the class in a more 'normal' way.

Comment: No... how/why does that look incorrect? It's exactly how I wrote another function earlier this week.

Comment: sorry didnt see all of the code,    i think its `Set Cci = Nothing`  at the end of it

Comment: @StevenMartin which ones? in `Class_Initialize` or in `GetRGB`?

Comment: well you declared it publicly and then privately and you set it to nothing so you would get an 91 error when the object doesnt exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined the private collection at the module level as `pCharColorItems`, but you never initialize it in the class' intialize method. Instead, you use a locally scoped `Colors` collection variable.

> ```
> Private Sub Class_Initialize()
>
>   Dim Cci As ChartColorItem
>   Dim Colors As Collection
>
>   Set Colors = New Collection
> ```

You need to use `pChartColorItems` instead.

```
Private Sub Class_Initialize()

  Dim Cci As ChartColorItem
  Dim Colors As Collection

  Set pChartColorItems = New Collection

  Set Cci = New ChartColorItem
  Cci.Red = 149
  Cci.Green = 55
  Cci.Blue = 53
  Cci.ColorID = "Pie1"
  pChartColorItems.Add Cci, Key:=Cci.ColorID
  Set Cci = Nothing

  Set Cci = New ChartColorItem
  Cci.Red = 148
  Cci.Green = 138
  Cci.Blue = 84
  Cci.ColorID = "Pie2"
  pChartColorItems.Add Cci, Key:=Cci.ColorID
  Set Cci = Nothing

End Sub
```

But there's another bug on this line of `GetRGB`.

> ```
>  x = RGB(Cci.Red, Cci.Green, Cci.Blue)
> ```

You declared `x` as an Integer, when the `RGB` function returns a long. The value of "Pie1" causes an overflow error.